# knockout kendo events fires twice

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, kendo-ui

Hej, I have a problem here with the [knockout-kendo](http://rniemeyer.github.io/knockout-kendo/) framework.
Every event gets fired twice.
 Can someone tell me whats wrong with my code?

I created a small [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bfycstr4/68/).

```
var StoreViewModel = function () {
    var self = this;
    this.stores = ko.observableArray(stores);
    this.selectedStore = ko.observable(stores[0].Id);

    // this event fires twice, dont know why!
    this.dataBoundEvent = function () {
        alert('databound event ...');
        //doSomething();
    };
    this.changeEvent = function () {
        alert('change event ...');
        //doSomething();
    };
};
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The binding event is called when the grid is initialize and when the data is set.

To stop this, just use `dataSource` instead of `data`

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <select data-bind="kendoDropDownList: {
        dataSource: stores,
        dataTextField: 'Address',
        dataValueField: 'Id',
        dataBound: dataBoundEvent,
        change: changeEvent
    }"></select>
</div>
```

dataSource is the normal way and the supported way of kendo.

Answer (score 1):

I believe dataBoundEvent is being called for

1. Binding the backing data (stores)
2. Binding the selected value (selectedStore)